# Set fill colour on arbitrary SVG served from website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

There are ways in which we can fetch SVG images from either a URL or local storage (one of which being `<img>` tags). Similarly, we can change the fill of inline SVGs by adjusting their fill in its CSS module.

However, I have struggled to find a way that we can render a SVG in a React functional component, where the URL is passed as a parameter, *and* we are able to set the path fill of the SVG. Is there any way of combining these two requirements?

I have tried passing URLs as `<img>` tags, experimented with fills using inline SVGs and explored other parts of Stack Overflow (including CSS masks and other CSS tricks) - however the issue I see is how to get JS string parameters into CSS to be able to use some of these solutions.
I have also found potential with `<use>` tags inside an inline SVG but am unsure how useful this could be for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The only way to format this from the outside, is when the SVG is actually contained directly in the document, meaning if you have embedded it as `<svg>...</svg>`. Embedding it as an image or object, encapsulates its content in a way that prevents you from getting that kind of access in the first place.